# Клиент-серверное приложение используя только ресурс телефона Android

Tags: android, kotlin

Интересует следующий вопрос - можно ли организовать серверную часть на телефоне на который будут прилетать нужные данные ? Т.к данных будет очень мало не рационально будет использовать полноценную БД. Дайте совет пожалуйста кто сталкивался с данной проблемой и кто как её решал, в какую сторону нужно копать и т.д. Всё что я не гуглил везде информация про локальный Sqlite который нельзя использовать другими клиентами, может можно на клиенте делать список и потом отправлять на основной телефон или планшет ? Буду рад любой информации.

Comment: Если данных прямо совсем мало и они редко обновляются - попробуйте посмотреть на тот же Firebase Database - получите бесплатную облачную БД. Но вообще, лучше нормальный сервак поднять, там базу запустить и в API обернуть. Сервак на телефоне поднимать очень сложно и ненадёжно. Как минимум нужен будет статический IP, за который надо отдельно платить. Да и тот только если от провайдера стационарного интернета получится получить. С собой такой телефон таскать не получится.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Будет всего 12 полей и 3-4 столбца, обновляться будут 1 раз в мес. и с каждого Нового года обновляться по кругу. Просто дело в том что нет возможности поднять сервер из-за отсутствия ПК который будет работать 24\7. Жаль что нельзя накостылить )) В любом случае большое вам спасибо за информацию.

Comment: С такими требованиями к БД вы можете хранить все свои данные в одном json файлике на любом файлообменнике или даже в гитхабе.

Comment: @zed Я таким методом смогу перезаписывать на гитхабе этот самый JSON файлик ? И как это выглядеть будет ? Никогда таким методом не пользовался ? ))

Comment: С ПК вносите изменения в файл, а клиенты на Адроид работают в режиме только для чтения. Если нужна запись с андроида, то придётся потрудиться с авторизацией и разобраться как пушить в гит.

Comment: @zed спасибо за идею

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Брал симку у билайна с выделенным IP.

Comment: @sapeg, ого, не знал, что такое бывает)